# Finding lines and curves on a surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

Suppose I have some equation of surface $S$ (let's take $f(u,v) = (uv,u+v,u^2 + v^2)$ for example). How do I find if there are some lines on a surface? If there are some lines on this surface, how do I understand if this is a ruled surface?

Comment: The Gaussian curvature of a ruled surface must equal zero at every point. Hence if there exists even a single point where the Gaussian curvature is not equal to zero, the surface is not ruled.

Comment: On a related note: if $P$ is a point through which a line passes, the Gaussian curvature at $P$ must be zero, so setting $\kappa(P) = 0$ and solving  typically limits your search a good deal.

Comment: @LeeMosher (and John, too): No, only for a *developable ruled surface* is $K=0$. For a general ruled surface, we can only say that $K\le 0$. Think of a saddle surface or a hyperboloid of one sheet.

Comment: I can't make my usual excuse of too little coffee. Ted's right, of course. I was reading "ruled" and thinking "developable", and then jumped forward to thinking that if there was a line, it also had to be one of the principal directions, which is completely wrong. Sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Lee and John suggested in comments, in order for a line through $P\in S$ to lie entirely in the surface, it is *necessary* (but not sufficient) that the Gaussian curvature $K(P)$ be nonpositive. Thus, you can conclude that if $K>0$ everywhere on $S$, there can be *no* lines contained in the surface. Ruled surfaces with $K=0$ everywhere are very special — they are called *developable ruled surfaces* and (locally) are either a plane, a (generalized) cylinder, a (generalized) cone, or the locus of tangent lines to a space curve. [See, for example, exercise 12 on p. 42 and exercise 10 on p. 65 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).]

Your surface $S$ is given parametrically, but it's not hard to see that it satisfies the cartesian equation $2x+z=y^2$. A line through $P=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given parametrically by $x=x_0+at$, $y=y_0+bt$, $z=z_0+ct$ for some scalars $a,b,c$. Your surface $S$ is given parametrically, but it's not hard to see that it is given by the cartesian equation $2x+z=y^2$. What happens when you substitute these into the equation of $S$? For the line to be wholly contained in $S$ the resulting equation must hold *for all* $t\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: How did you see $2x + z = y^2$? I didn't see this at all.

Comment: Start with $y=u+v$ and square it. :)